# Definition of a Markov process on the real numbers.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, markov-process

I was going through the Grimmett and Stirzaker probability textbook and I stumbled upon this definition for a Markov process on $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Definition.** The continuous-time process $X$, taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, is called a **Markov process** if the following holds:
> \begin{multline}
> \mathbb{P}\bigl( X(t_n) \leq x \mid 
> X(t_1) = x_1, \dots, X(t_{n-1}) = x_{n-1} \bigr) \\
> = \mathbb{P}\bigl( X(t_n) \leq x \mid 
> X(t_{n-1}) = x_{n-1} \bigr) 
> \end{multline}
> for all $x, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}$, and all increasing sequences $t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_n$ of times.

I find it kinda weird because here the probability of the event $X(t_{n-1}) = x_{n-1}$ might be null, so we might not be able to condition on it. I was expecting a definition like the following instead (so that it is valid on the Borel set) :
\begin{multline}
\mathbb{P}(X(t_n) \leq x 
\mid X(t_1) \leq x_1, \dots, X(t_{n-1}) \leq x_{n-1}) \\
= \mathbb{P}(X(t_n) \leq x_n 
\mid X(t_{n-1}) \leq x_{n-1})
\end{multline}

Comment: One obstacle is that the equation you've written is in general false for Markov chains. For example, if the Markov chain is a continuous random walk with a maximum speed, then an inequality $X(t_i) \le x_i$ might *guarantee* that $X(t_n) \le x$ when $X(t_{n-1}) \le x_{n-1}$ does not.

Comment: *Notation:* use `\mid` to build sets, as it has better horizontal whitespace (treated as a `\mathrel` like `=`).

Comment: What's written in G&S is just an elementary notation for markov kernels / regular conditional distributions. So there is actually no issue

Comment: Thank you for your replies. But what if $X$ was a gaussian process so that $X_{t_{n-1}}$ has a non-singular normal distribution, the event $X_{t_{n-1}} = x_{n-1}$ would have probability zero and we wouldn't be able to condition by it right? Sorry for being dense.

Comment: @DeadKarlMarx see my comment